# Transit visa requirements at Narita Airport

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, nrt

I am an Indian citizen and currently staying in United States on J-1
Exchange Visitor visa. I will be traveling from Dallas Fort Worth (DFW) to New
Delhi (India) on 19th July. I have a layover of 22 hours at Narita Airport.
I do not plan leave the terminal, both my incoming and departure flight are from Terminal 2 at Narita airport. I have booked the flights through Japan Airlines.

Will I be requiring a transit visa?

I have heard of some rules change at Narita Airport, hence asking this as a separate question.

Also, if the visa is required is it possible to get it at on arrival at NRT or do I need to apply for visa at the Japanese Embassy at Houston?

Comment: I have already tried asking the Narita Airport staff, but they don't have information regarding it. I have heard rules are changed recently, that is why I have posted this as a new question.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your comment, but that answer seems to be 5 year old, and I have heard about some recent rules change. I asked the question again, hoping that any one who traveled recently will be able to help.

Comment: I have not heard of any recent change.

Comment: @fkraiem Well, I called Japan Airlines to ask about the transit visa requirements, they told me that the rules been changed so it would be better to confirm with Narita Airport Staff, and when I emailed the airport officials they replied that you need to confirm with embassy. I haven't yet received a response from embassy of japan.

Comment: @bonacci If any changes had been implemented, it would reflect the Information in Timatic. You'll be fine (read my answer)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This one is about **transit** with the intention to stay airside, the suggested dupe is about venturing **landside**. Voted to leave open.

Comment: @bonacci: I plan to take a similar trip (I'm an Indian citizen), San Diego to Delhi via Narita, have an overnight 20h layover. Was wondering what your experience was? Is it enforced that one leaves the transit area and enters Japan and if so, did you get the shore pass? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you **will not** need a transit visa to connect at Narita.

However, the transit area closes at night, so if your flight departs the next day you will Need to enter Japan and spend the night there.

This should be no Problem, because by presenting your passport and boarding pass you will get an entry sticker allowing you to stay for 72 hours (this is called a Shore pass, and is for People with connections that are not possible on the same day).

This is the information that the airlines have (it's a database called Timatic).

Don't trust embassies: they often have outdated info, or sometimes outright don't know what they're talking about. An example is the Japanese embassy in Delhi, which doesn't even mention the existance of the Shore Pass on its website, instead saying all Indians Need a Transit visa

Comment: ,Thanks a lot for the information. Yes, my flight departs on the next day and will have to get a shore pass if that's case. I would like to confirm one more thing, do I need to apply beforehand somewhere(embassy)  for a getting a shore pass? Thanks!

Comment: I'm very surprised by your advice not to trust embassies. The ultimate, near-irrefutable source on who can or cannot enter Japan is the Japanese government. The Japanese embassy is an agency of the Japanese government. In contrast, airlines and airports are not authoritative and may be expected to give overly cautious advice (e.g., telling you that you need a visa when, actually, you don't), to cover their own asses. Do you have any evidence for your claim that embassies are unreliable in this regard?

Comment: @bonacci Nope, a shore pass is not a visa, just a temporary visa exemption for Transit passengers. So just show your passport, Boarding pass, and be ready to answer some questions (they may want to see that you have enough Money to cover your stay), and it's pasted into the passport. It's similar to the Stickers I (being Swedish) get, only it's called a Shore Pass, is only valid for 72 hours and is only for your Kind of case

Comment: @DavidRicherby The Airlines will be the ones taking you there, and they don't give a damn about what an embassy says. If in doubt, then usually whatever it says in Timatic, that's what they go by (unless they have their own rules, which most Airlines don't). Also I remember at least one Japanese embassy (I think in Delhi) stating that Indians Need a Transit visa - the Shore pass wasn't even mentioned even though it absolutely exists. Another example: Tajik embassies frequently claim VOA doesn't exist in the Country (!!!)

Comment: @Crazydre And it's the Japanese border officials who'll be deciding whether or not you get into Japan. They don't give a damn about what an airline says.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Correct, **however**, Timatic is based on info that local Immigration authorities provide to IATA. If a Country hasn't reported updates in a while, IATA will actually contact them and ask if there's anything that Needs Change (and no, I'm not an IATA employee, but I do have contact with them)

Comment: @bonacci BTW, it is possible you Need to ask for a Shore Pass application form at the *airline check-in desk* (I have read different versions). Call Japan Airlines and ask

Comment: I was talking about the assertion that immigration inspectors are private contractors. About the shore pass, my understanding is that the airline must apply for it on the passenger's behalf, and that they very rarely do it. But there is very little first-hand information about it.

Comment: @fkraiem It used to be something that was only issued in exceptional cases (it used to say that in Timatic as well), but currently it simply says one can be obtained if there are no connecting flights to the Destination on the same day and you arrive and depart from a border crossing Point in the same region class (and OP is even arriving and departing from the same Airport, Narita)

Comment: @fkraiem Tell you what, I'll call JAL right now and ask

Comment: FWIW a semi-official translation of the relevant legal provisions is here: http://www.japaneselawtranslation.go.jp/law/detail_main?re=02&vm=02&id=2647#en_ch3sc4at3

Comment: @bonacci I just spoke to the American JAL Office on the phone. They said the airline does not apply for a Shore pass in advance - you do once you get to Immigration. Simply Show your passport+connecting Boarding pass and explain (if asked) that you want a Shore pass because you Need to stay overnight for the Connection.

Comment: @Crazydre, Thanks man! for your help, I was really confused, but now I don't have worry about all this. Just to reconfirm, Indian citizen can get this shore pass right?, It is not necessary to be a citizen of the country with which Japan has signed VISA waiver program?

Comment: @bonacci Shore passes are for People who **do** Need a visa to actually **visit** Japan. I, being Swedish (we do **not** Need visas to visit Japan), automatically get an entry sticker valid for 90 days; the Shore pass is a Special sticker for only 72 hours, only for People like you who **do** Need a visa to visit Japan but who only Needs to stay overnight for a Connection.

Comment: @bonacci And finally, if JAL should ask about your documents at check-in, just tell them you're going for a Shore Pass. They know about it very well (as I spoke to them)